# Pressing ctrl+space is detected as ctrl+c

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was defined a global hotkey (ctrl+space) for Play/Pause in VLC media player on Windows 7.

Until yesterday everything was OK, but today I see it doesn't work.

So I looked into settings of VLC. That hotkey was present. I tried to reassign it, but every time I press ctrl+space it is detected as ctrl+c! Restarted PC, but no luck.

Space itself is working.

Do I need to change my keyboard?

**edit:**

I plugged another keyboard. It's the same.

I also tried to assign this hotkey for shortcut of a file (.lnk) in it's properties dialog. Again it is detected as Ctrl+Alt+C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a hot key conflict problem, it is recommended that you download a hot key conflict detection software, such as **Windows Hotkey Explorer** or **hotkey commander**, it can display the currently occupied shortcut keys, and navigate to the relevant program, you can try to detect.

[image]

This is the [hotkey commander tool](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/help.html) that I use, you can refer to it.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. A long time ago I was installed Ochepyatka and configured Ctrl+Space for it. Recently I used it again and didn't notice it's yet running. Hotkey Commander is very useful.